# Converter uma variável byte em string?

Tags: python, string, byte

Boa tarde gostava de converter uma variável byte em string.

Tenho o seguinte código;

```
print(str.encode(frase))
```

que dá a seguinte saída;

```
b'Ola'
```

e queria antes;

```
Ola
```

Encontrei uma forma de converter mas apenas com uma string não com uma variável;

```
b"abcde".decode("utf-8")
```

A minha pergunta é como eu utilizo este código com uma variável?

Comment: O que quer dizer com isso? Tipo ter esse nome como variável? Tente usar `eval()` e `exec()`.

Comment: o que queria fazer é isto por exemplo; b"abcde".decode("utf-8") e colocar em "abcde" uma variável e fazer a converção

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz sentido... Se a variável contém bytes, é só usar o método decode normalmente. Tipo: `meus_bytes = b'Ola'` depois `meus_bytes.decode("utf-8")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Python, os valores que "estão dentro" das variáveis (técnicamente é "associados aos nomes") são todos objetos - assim como os literais digitados direto no programa são também objetos. Literais são, por exemplo, o que você está chamando de string - todos os valores que são digitados no programa - seja `b"maca"`, números como `123.45`, etc....

Para a linguagem, quando vamos usar um método de um tipo de objeto, tanto faz se o objeto foi digitado diretamente no código do programa, como um literal, ou se está numa variável.

Ou seja:

```
meus_bytes = b"frase de teste"
minha_string = meus_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

- O método `decode` com a notação de `.`, é chamado com o . depois do nome da variável, e funciona da mesma forma que o `.` depois do literal em `b"frase_de_Teste".decode()`.

Um truque relacionado mas pouco conhecido, é que mesmo métodos associados aos números - tanto ponto flutuante como inteiros, podem ser chamados direto dos literais - mas nesse caso é necessário pelo menos um espaço em branco separando os dígitos dos números, para diferenciar o acesso atributos do ponto decimal - por exemplo: `1234 .to_bytes(2, "little")`

Answer (score 0):

O método `.decode` funciona com variáveis também, não apenas com literais. Rode o seguinte código e veja:

```
original = 'Olá, mundo'
encodado = original.encode('utf-8')
decodado = encodado.decode('utf-8') # Funciona perfeitamente!

print(encodado)
print(decodado)
print(original == decodado)
```